# How do I compare two objects based on their base class?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I would like to be able to compare two classes derived from the same abstract class in C#. The following code illustrates my problem.

I now I could fix the code by making `BaseClass` non abstract and then return a `new BaseClass` object in `ToBassClass()`. But isn't there a more elegant and efficient solution?

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
   BaseClass(int x)
   {
       X = x;
   }

   int X { get; private set; }

   // It is probably not necessary to override Equals for such a simple class,
   // but I've done it to illustrate my point.
   override Equals(object other)
   {
       if (!other is BaseClass)
       {
           return false;
       }

       BaseClass otherBaseClass = (BaseClass)other;

       return (otherBaseClass.X == this.X);
   }

   BaseClass ToBaseClass()
   {
       // The explicit is only included for clarity.
       return (BaseClass)this;
   }
}

class ClassA : BaseClass
{
   ClassA(int x, int y)
       : base (x)
   {
       Y = y;
   }

   int Y { get; private set; }
}

class ClassB : BaseClass
{
   ClassB(int x, int z)
       : base (x)
   {
       Z = z;
   }

   int Z { get; private set; }
}

var a = new A(1, 2);
var b = new B(1, 3);

// This fails because despite the call to ToBaseClass(), a and b are treated
// as ClassA and ClassB classes so the overridden Equals() is never called.
Assert.AreEqual(a.ToBaseClass(), b.ToBaseClass());
```

Comment: Also, int Z { get; private Z; } should be int Z { get; private set; } ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on *where* exactly you want to test for equality. Clearly `ClassA` and `ClassB` instances will never be "equal" in the real sense of that word, so overriding `Equals` to behave like this might actually cause some weird bugs in your code.

But if you want to compare them based on a **specific criteria**, then you can implement a specific [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) (or several comparers) which suites your needs.

So, in this case you would have:

```
/// <Summary>
/// Compares two classes based only on the value of their X property.
/// </Summary>
public class ComparerByX : IEqualityComparer<BaseClass>
{
     #region IEqualityComparer<BaseClass> Members

     public bool Equals(BaseClass a, BaseClass b)
     {
         return (a.X == b.X);
     }

     public int GetHashCode(BaseClass obj)
     {
         return obj.X.GetHashCode();
     }

     #endregion

}
```

**[Edit]** Regarding comment:

Note that this doesn't have anything with overriding the `Equals` method.

But you will be able to check for equality like this:

```
IEqualityComparer<BaseClass> comparer = new ComparerByX();
Assert.True(comparer.Equals(a, b));
```

This may not seem like a great thing at first, but it gives you several advantages:

**a)** You can have as many `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementations as you want. Depending on the case, it may turn up that you `Equals` override is not so great after all. Then you risk breaking all of your code depending on this.

**b)** There are actually many classes which use `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare items.

For example, you might want to use the `BaseClass` as a key in a dictionary. In that case, you would use the [`Dictionary<Key,Value>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) constructor overload which accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
Dictionary<BaseClass, SomeOtherClass> dictionary 
    = new Dictionary<BaseClass, SomeOtherClass>(new ComparerByX());
```

This way, dictionary will use the custom `ComparerByX` during key lookup.

Also, for example, if you are using LINQ, you can check the [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method example. It also supports an overload which returns distinct values, but compared using the specified custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: Will this make a.ToBaseClass() == b.ToBaseClass(), and still keep a != b?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as Freed pointed out it's a bit odd to use `Assert.True` here - did you mean `Assert.AreEqual`? If so, I'd have expected this to work (even without the `ToBaseClass` call), although it would depend on the test framework.

Equality is tricky when it comes to inheritance though. Personally, I'd create an appropriate `IEqualityComparer<BaseClass>` which explicitly says "I'm going to test this specific aspect of an object" - which means that inheritance basically doesn't get involved.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code doesn't compile. Second, when your code is fixed so that it does compile (in particular, `Assert.True` is changed to `Assert.AreEqual`), I see the results that you are expecting. And that's a good thing as that's the correct behavior. But you can't rely on inheritors not overriding `Object.Equals` so if you want comparison to go by the base class only then you should implement `IEqualityComparer<BaseClass>`.

Here's a version of your code as you probably intended it so that it does compile:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass(int x) { X = x; }

    public int X { get; private set; }

    public override bool  Equals(object other) {
        if (!(other is BaseClass)) {
            return false; 
        }

        BaseClass otherBaseClass = (BaseClass)other;
        return (otherBaseClass.X == this.X);
    }

    public BaseClass ToBaseClass() {
        return (BaseClass)this;
    }
}

class ClassA : BaseClass {
    public ClassA(int x, int y) : base (x) {
        Y = y;
    }

    public int Y { get; private set; }
}

class ClassB : BaseClass {
    public ClassB(int x, int z) : base (x) {
        Z = z;
    }

    public int Z { get; private set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = new ClassA(1, 2);
        var b = new ClassB(1, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(a.ToBaseClass(), b.ToBaseClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seriously recommend using KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects (although I am not the author - it is very flexible, effective and so far, bug free!).

I did the same thing to compare 2 objects based on a base class.

1) Create a "BaseClassComparer" which takes the type you want to use for comparisons:

```
using System;
using KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects;

namespace Compare
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This allows us to compare objects based on a particular class (ie so we can compare on base classes)
    /// </summary>
    public class BaseClassComparer : KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects.TypeComparers.ClassComparer
    {


        private readonly Type _compareType;
        internal BaseClassComparer(Type compareType, RootComparer rootComparer) : base(rootComparer)
        {

            _compareType = compareType;
        }

        public override void CompareType(CompareParms parms)
        {
            parms.Object1Type = _compareType;
            parms.Object2Type = _compareType;

            base.CompareType(parms);
        }

        public override bool IsTypeMatch(Type type1, Type type2)
        {
            if (((_compareType.IsAssignableFrom(type1)) && (_compareType.IsAssignableFrom(type2)))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add this class to the Kellerman comparer:

```
_compare = New CompareLogic
_compare.Config.CustomComparers.Add(New BaseClassComparer(compareType, RootComparerFactory.GetRootComparer()))
```

And compare away. Only differences between the base type (compareType) will be checked/reported...

Comment: I know it's been many years, but I just tested this, and I can't get it to work with the latest version of CompareNetObjects. It compares the entire object, not just the superclass portion of the object.